# Quadratic Formula without import math

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody help me write a code using python 3 that can solve the quadratic formula without using "import math"? Please !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for completed code are not on-topic for StackOverflow. You **must** show your efforts and any issues that you encounter while doing that, or your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Hint: you can do exponentiation without the `math` module.

Comment: the only thing you would need from `math` is `sqrt`, which can be achieved with exponentiation by 0.5

Comment: The only thing you need from `math` to implement the quadratic formula is a square root function.  Why don't you try making one of those, and then if you have problems post here again with specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aurora001 mentioned, you should not ask for completed code. However, I think addressing the method you might use could be a good answer to your question, and I hope others agree. This is how I would approach the problem:

- Prompt for input to get the coefficients `a`, `b`, and `c`.
- Write a method that finds the square root of a number (several algorithms exist and can be found with a Google search) - There are also more built-in ways to do exponentiation in Python without the math module but this seems like it is for a class and the point may be to see if you can write a `sqrt` implementation.
- Write a method that uses your custom square root implementation to solve the quadratic equation using the coefficients as parameters.
- Test your two methods by doing a few test cases.

I hope this helps; post another question if you have more specific issues. I have noticed more people will be willing to assist if you generate your own code and ask about specific problems that you cannot solve.